# CompatibilityRange on SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

Why is following command returning 15 and not 16?

```
> [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCompatibilityRange]::NewVersion

MaxCompatibilityLevel         MinCompatibilityLevel     DefaultCompatibilityLevel                      Singular
---------------------         ---------------------     -------------------------                      --------
15                            15                            15                          True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Microsoft did not introduce CompatibilityLevel 16, yet. Therefore, the currently highest CompatibilityLevel is 15.

Comment: Ok fair enough - but what does that mean? And does that mean that I have to specify `-CompatibilityLevel 15` on the `New-SPSite` CmdLet even though im working on SharePoint 2016 (with internal version 16)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but to me it sounds as if a Site-Collection created in '16 would run in '13 since they share the same CompatibilityLevel. But that's just speculation. Yes you have to specify _-CompatibilityLevel 15_.